# Sum TimeSpan in IQueryable query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I can not sum time of episodes until I convert query to `IEnumerable`

this my code

```
IQueryable<Course> result = db.Courses;
GetCoursesViewModel list = new GetCoursesViewModel();
list.Courses = await result
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(getCourses.Take)
            .Select(c => new GetCoursesListViewModel
            {
                Id = c.CourseId,
                Title = c.CourseTitle,
                Price = c.CoursePrice,
                Group = c.CourseGroup.GroupTitle,
                Level = c.CourseLevel.LevelTitle,
                Status = c.CourseStatus.StatusTitle,
                ImageName = c.CourseImageName,
                EpisodeCount = c.CourseEpisodes.Count,
                ShortDescription = c.CourseShortDescription,
                /*TotalTime = new TimeSpan(c.CourseEpisodes.Sum(e => e.EpisodeTime.Ticks)),*/ could not be translated.
                Teacher = c.User.UserName
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way I can get the total duration using IQueryable?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. It's not about IQueryable, what you tried simply can't be translated to SQL.  What are `CourseEpisodes`, `EpisodeTime` or `Ticks`? Do you really store ticks as a bigint in the database? Or is the actual field a `time` field named `EpisodeTime`  which was mapped to a `TimeStamp` property?

Comment: What database are you using? In SQL Server `time` represents a time-of-day, not a duration and *can't* be added. You can't force EF to generate a query that allows this through TimeSpan methods.

Comment: Is `EpisodeTime` some other type, eg `bigint` that was mapped to `TimeSpan` through a custom value conversion? [There's an active issue about this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27103) as EF Core can't use the base field type for SQL generation in such cases yet. Nothing says that the base field is a `bigint` with ticks either, it could be seconds or a string. The fix right now is to map the actual field, allowing EF to use it in SQL,  and use a non-mapped property to return the `Timestamp`.